# Java choosing a way to read data from external file

Tags: java, properties-file

I am working on this Java application where basically I want to read data from a file which is stored externally in the form of say a text file or properties file. My data basically consists of multiple people names and their emails.
Usually I would choose a database and just connect it with my application and be over with it. But honestly I do not have that much data and I cannot hardcode this either since this application if used by other people would have different data values of names and emails.
My question is basically what would be a good way to store and read these data and pull out this data to be used. I have considered using and reading Properties File in Java, Text files and XML file but I am unsure which is better or the difference in usability. Any other ways are also welcome! Thanks!

Comment: Let us know the exact extension that you have right now with you as a file

Comment: I have not actually decided on what sort of file I would like to store my data as. In regards to the question I want to know say what would be easier to implement and such! To clarify further my data is in the form of <Jack><jack@example.com>, <John><john@example.com> and so on so forth!

Comment: then XML is good, JSON much better

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Would you mind clarifying the reason though why you suggest those specifically?

Comment: Have you seen XML and JSON files before? I am not asking this to make you feel bad or anything.. if you have not I just wanted to make sure I understand it in much deeper way

Comment: I have but I have not worked with them before in any context so my knowledge is far from complete on how to utilise them. That is why I want to understand why either or is better! Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126254/discussion-between-shreyas-sarvothama-and-ren).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I would recommend, don't go for text files as there is no format/structure for the same.

In XML you can store more complex (e.g. hierarchical) data than in a properties file. So it depends on your usecase. If you just want to store a small number of direct properties a properties file is easier to handle (though the Java properties class can read XML based properties, too).

It would make sense to keep your configuration interface as generic as possible anyway, so you have no problem to switch to another representation ( e.g. by using Apache Commons Configuration ) if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Stick to properties if your data is not hierarchical and you don't care about typing.

Use [Jackson yaml](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-yaml) parsing if it is somewhat hierarchical, that feels much more human readable compared to xml.